# How do I create a formula that refers to cell references that are located in another cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I need to create a table that refers to a certain cell in the first column, and the corresponding data that is located a certain number of cells away from the first cell in another column.

a1: =**Monday!B28**

b1: =OFFSET(**Monday!B28**,2,0)

How do I get part of the formula in b1 to refer to the cell reference that is stated in a1? The bolded part is the content I need carried over.

I'm trying to keep this as simple as possible so you understand what my issue is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to mix and match the =indirect() ,=Formulatext(), and =substitute() formulas.

Since you want to extract the actual reference from cell A1, you'll first need to clean it up and get only "Monday!B28"

For that to actually happen, follow these steps.

1. Convert the formula in A1 to text by using formulatext.

   ```
   =formulatext(A1)
   ```
2. Then remove the "=" sign by using substitute.

   ```
    =substitute(formulatext(A1),"=","")
   ```
3. And then you can use indirect in your original formula, so the end result would be:

   ```
   =offset(substitute(formulatext(A1),"=",""),2,0)
   ```

And there you go. I'd recommend assigning each step it's own column so as keep with proper excel Practice of not having formulas longer than your thumb... but that's personal preference.

Comment: THANK-YOU! I tried fitting it into a single cell, but there were too many functions in one cell. For anyone wondering how I've set it up:

a1: =MONDAY!B28

b1: =SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(A1)"=","")

c1: =OFFSET(INDIRECT(B1),2,0)


The indirect function needs to be applied for this formula to work.

Answer (score 2):

You use Indirect:

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(A1),2,0)
```